# Excel: How to return a unique list array as a result of a two column lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns of equal number of rows with repeating values in each. The first column is in order by number, the second column is secondarily ordered by number. I want a list of all the unique values that pair with a given value from the first column. 
Example:

Col A: {1;1;1;1;2;2;2;2;3;3;3;3;4;4;4;4}
Col B: {a;a;b;c;a;b;b;c;.....etc}

I want to specify a cell that contains the value in Col A, say "2", and return the unique values as an array into a list of cells the values from Col B. So: {a;b;c}.

Right now I have a column indexed array formula using Small to list through the full set of B matches, then I have a second column indexed array formula to sort out the unique values from that, but I can't seem to find a way to make it one formula.

So now I have (say col C):

> {=INDEX(A:A&B:B,SMALL(IF(A:A=A1,ROW(A:A)),ROW(1:1),2)}

which I fill down to the number of rows that covers all the values for a given A value.
Then I have another column to find the uniques:

> {=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,C:C),0)),"")}

which I fill down to the number of rows that covers the unique values

Comment: Can you help to share some sample data to test the formulas? .. ( :